# applicationwillenterforeground is not called on iOS 11 Beta

Tags: ios, ios11

I have an existing app that works on iOS 10 or before, where as some of the features are broken in iOS 11 Beta 8. When I analyzed and debugged, understand that appdelegate methods "applicationDidEnterBackground" and "applicationwillenterforeground" are not called when app is coming from background to foreground immediately after tapping home button.
Important note: You should be doing the things like Tapping on home button followed by Tapping on App icon in no longer than 1sec.

Using Xcode Version 9.0 beta 6 (9M214v), testing on iPhone 7 Simulator.

Please find the attached sample code along with recorded video.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zba7go5d7wo6j1n/Test.zip?dl=0

Did anybody face this issue? Seems, a bug in iOS 11.

Comment: Create any project with Xcode 8, add below log statements in the appdelegate.m - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"in applicationWillEnterForeground");
  }
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     NSLog(@"in applicationDidBecomeActive");
}. Now quit Xcode 8 and open the project with Xcode9-Beta.

Comment: is this possible to attach your sample project

Comment: You can find the sample app, also contains recorded video. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vf3gdsp3197xoco/Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: give the moment

Comment: its working fine for me in xcode9 beta 5, whats your xcode version

Comment: Xcode Version 9.0 beta 6 (9M214v).

Comment: i tried in your way ,I got answer, is not a bug

Comment: Are you not able to reproduce the issue? Please check the attached video in that folder. Open the code with Xcode 8.x, you will not see the issue.

Comment: ya i seen the video ,but i am not faced the issue, if  u r in doubt submit your bug in radar may be you get answer , i checked in Xcode 8.x and Xcode 9 beta 5

Comment: Added few more logs in the delegate methods. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zba7go5d7wo6j1n/Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: I had same issue some one solved it ?